# What is this Prickly Plant Sending Out Runners

Tags: identification, invasive

I'm clearing some bushes out my backyard and found these awful prickly plants. They look to be part of a bigger plant that isn't prickly and have sent runners out all over. I'm trying to id them so I can figure out how best to eradicate them. 
[image: main plant]
[image: new shoots]

Comment: In which region do you live?  To me they seems Rosaceae. Something like raspberries, gooseberries and similar. Wild varieties are often weeds.

Comment: I live in Salt Lake City, Utah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rosa Rugosa  I've added a pretty informative site.  We sold these plants at all the nurseries I've worked or known. They are invasive, yes they are, birds eat the hips and poop them out. Easiest thing to do is PULL them out using gloves of course.  When ever you see a newbie start come up cut it off.  This will effectively starve the Rosa rugosa out...just be vigilant for baby plants. Best time to eradicate is to pull baby plants before they become a gnarly underground network.[rosa rugosa](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?taxonid=286364)

Make incredible hedges that bad guys and robbers will not be able to penetrate?

Comment: Based on other pictures of Rosa Rugosa found on google, this looks like the exact plant I've got.

Comment: @TomPridham  - of course it does - most roses are grafted onto Rosa rugosa or rosa canina rootstocks - as I said, this is likely the rootstock growing from what was once a grafted rose.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like rose growth, most likely off a rootstock; possibly the grafted part of the original rose has died and now just the root stock is left and spreading everywhere. It's entirely separate from the plant or tree with smooth trunks mixed in with it. Which is difficult, because it will be next to impossible to extract all the roots and runners because they'll be mixed  in with the tree/shrub roots.

If you do not want to remove the smooth stemmed plant, then you need to dig around a bit to expose the top of the roots of the rose,  cut down the topgrowth and treat the roots and lower stems with a brushwood/tree stump killer. If you don't mind taking out the other shrub, then grub them both out, but expect the roots of the rose to be widespread as well as going down deep in the ground.

Comment: Could not remove a similar plant no matter how much I dug.

Comment: I was able to kill a multiflora rose (different genus) with Triclopyr (a stump and brush killed, like Bamboo recommended). You will need to treat every cane that you see. It's a little late for a basal application, so your best bet may be to cut the canes 18" from the ground and gently apply the undiluted chemical to the top of the cane, letting it travel down the cane to the ground. Note that too much triclopyr may kill the other plant in the photo (I've known it to "travel" in the soil and kill other plants nearby).

Comment: Starving this rose works just as fast and effectively as adding a systemic pesticide.  Plants need to replenish carbohydrate storage to use for energy. No photosynthetic growth equals no food for plant life and that equals death or at least control. No need for pesticide at all. Just chop chop with pruning shears. In 2 years even with spotty vigilance, this rosa rugosa will be gone. I'd look on the other side of the fence and pull mulch, soil away from bottom of fence or you'll lose your fence from rot. Grins, just fyi?

Answer (score 2):

Rugosa roses are characterized by rugose leaves, which means deeply creased. They have heavily etched veins in their leaves. That looks more like a hybrid spinosissima Rose, and may have been a desirable ornamental. They do spread by suckers, however. Without seeing the flowers, it is impossible to ID The cultivar to know exactly what it was. I would have suggested a wait-and-see approach.  I don't know what the smooth bark belongs to, but it's conceivable that it was the plant that invaded that flower bed, and not the rose.